# Where to display $.post information?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, post

I have this:

```
$.post("http://www.roblox.com/My/Money.aspx/GetMyTransactions", {"startindex": 20, "transactiontype": "purchase"});
```

and I don't know how to "update" the page or show the information from the post. Help?

Edit:

I just want to know how to change the contents of a div "TransactionsContainer"

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/ a good read on how to manipulate the HTML DOM

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("http://www.roblox.com/My/Money.aspx/GetMyTransactions", {"startindex": 20, "transactiontype": "purchase"}, function(result){
        $("span").html(result);
    });
});
</script>

<span>Result will be displayed here</span>
```

---

Read more about [jQuery .post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: Is there a way to just change the contents of a full page? (I'm using this in the Google Chrome console.)

Comment: @LoganRichey $("body").html(result); will replace the entire html of the body with your result...

Comment: @sharf this: http://gyazo.com/ac92d53a5496913fbf47d4d4b520dda9

and the page won't load. i'm assuming that's because of the error.

Comment: Is `www.roblox.com` on the same domain as the request page ?

Comment: @PedroLobito Yes. It is on http://www.roblox.com/My/Money.aspx#/#MyTransactions_tab

and I checked for the GetMyTransactions API with the Network tab with google chromes inspect element

Comment: The url + hashtag `roblox.com/My/Money.aspx#/#MyTransactions_tab` doesn't match the one on your question.

Comment: @PedroLobito Yeah, I know, but the API I used in the $.post is what they use for loading transactions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Instead of only posting the code, it is better to also explain what you did and why you did it.

Comment: theres a link for jquery post function that contains all the information

shortly `.done()` will be called out after the request, and `data` will be returned/readed from the link :)

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/177764 on why StackOverflow doesn't consider (only) links containing information a good answer

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a third argument to `$.post` which takes a function.  The function is provided the response from the server as an argument.

```
$.post(
  "http://www.roblox.com/My/Money.aspx/GetMyTransactions",
  {"startindex": 20, "transactiontype": "purchase"},
  function(response) {
    // response contains the response object from the server.
    $('[some selector]').text(response);
  }
);
```